# What electronic component is this? - sensor part of particulate matter sensor

Tags: design, components, laser, optoelectronics, optics

[image]
[image]

What electronic component is this?

This is a part of a laser sensor which measures particulates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a photodiode to measure the light reflected from the particles.

Comment: Just one? A standard one? I can't believe it measures particulates so precisely.

Comment: Not sure how to respond to that. Yes a photodiode, fairly large die size by the looks of it.

Comment: The precision likely doesn't depend on the photo-sensor. It is more likely to be controlled by other factors like the diameter of the laser beam, metering the air-flow through the measurement chamber, etc.  Furthermore, it is likely factory calibrated for the exact sensitivity of the diode fitted to each assembly.